# php image gallery loop randomly leaving out images

Tags: php, arrays, image

I have a gallery script that checks a directory and should dump all images from the directory to a table.  However - it seems to randomly not display at least one image from the directory in the table.  I've tried doing a var_dump on the array and can see all of the images in the array.  Array keys 6 and 11 and 16 are not displaying in the output.  There are 19 images in the directory and only 16 are displaying.

Here is the code:

```
    <?php

    // open this directory 
    $myDirectory = opendir("images/");

    // get each entry
    while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {
        $dirArray[] = $entryName;
    }

    // close directory
    closedir($myDirectory);

    //  count elements in array
    $indexCount = count($dirArray);

    var_dump($dirArray);

    ?>

    <table cellpadding="5"><tr>

        <?php
        for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
            $extension = substr($dirArray[$index], -3);
            if ($extension == 'jpg'){ // list only jpgs
                if ($i < 4) {
        echo '<td valign="top">
<center><a href="images/'.$dirArray[$index].'" rel="lightbox">
<img src="images/'.$dirArray[$index].'" width="200" >
</a><br>'.$dirArray[$index].'</td>';
        $i++;
    } elseif ($i == 4) {
        echo '</tr><tr>';
        $i = 0;
    }   
            }   
        } 
        ?>
```

Comment: Does some file have the extension JPG? In other words, is the extension in uppercase? Then rename all files to lowercase, that's the best option or expand your **if** to this `if ($extension == 'jpg' || $extension == 'JPG')`

Comment: No - I checked that first off and all of the files have a .jpg extension.

Comment: or you can use $extension = strtolower(substr($dirArray[$index], -3)); to make extension lower case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here. Some of them does not being printed out because they doesn't match the if statement before the elseif.

```
} elseif ($i == 4) {
    echo '</tr><tr>';
    $i = 0;
}
```

Replace `elseif` with `if`